# Gnome3, get rid of foot bar showing programs

Tags: gnome3, settings

I was tweaking gnome with the gnome tweak tool and suddenly a bar appeared at the bottom of the screen. See picture: [image]
It's the bar with Alanis Morissette and Lightweight Django.

I've installed some shell extensions. I suspect shellshape could be the culprit, but I find no settings in it regarding this.

I also tried toggling the gnome extension 'windows list', but that didn't work either.

Another gnome extension, TaskBAr, is not installed.

Answer (score 1):

That's a standard Gnome *Classic* feature.

Make sure the Gnome shell extension Window List is disable.

Then, just log out from your user account, and by the settings (look for a gear) choose Gnome instead of Gnome Classics.

Answer (score 0):

Hover the mouse over the panel on free space, press `Alt` + right mouse (for me it is `Alt` but it may be `Ctrl`, `Ctrl+Super`, try also with no modifier). One of the options is "Delete this panel", or look at "Properties" and choose appropriate settings.
[image]

Comment: Nope, none of these worked.

Comment: that is, you get this menu but no options works, or you don't get the menu?

Comment: I don't get the menu, no matter what combination of alt/ctrl/super and right clicks.

Comment: Alt+Windows+right mouse ? Win/Super. And you should click on free space on the panel.

Comment: Yes I tried this and nothing, but maybe this keys are configured for something else.

Comment: maybe helps [https://askubuntu.com/questions/125662/how-to-reset-gnome-panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125662/how-to-reset-gnome-panel)